# Python-loop running over every cell in a dataframe (columns and rows)

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to write a loop in python that checks every single element of a dataframe and assigns a new value to it. More specifically, the operation log(x,y)-log(x-1,y) (x,y being row and column index) shall be executed for every cell. However, with some specifications for cases where the respective cell is 0. I already specified these cases in my code below. Then, I want to store the new values in a new dataframe which has exactly the same shape as the old one. I already managed to let my code run over all rows of one column and create a list out of the values, however, I don't know how to also make it change the column after it's done with all rows of one column.

This is exemplary data I created to get a better understanding of my issue and of how the loop is running. My data is actually a Dataframe with >6000 rows and 30 columns.

```
data = {'date': ["2004-01-01", "2004-01-02", "2004-01-03","2004-01-04"],
        'a': [100, 0, 0, 50],'b': [5, 76, 3, 100], 'c': [80, 0, 22, 100]}

data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
data.set_index("date", inplace=True)

log_diff=[np.nan] # fill with NaN since first row cannot be differenced

x=1
y=0

while x<4:
    if np.logical_and(data.iloc[x,y] > 0, data.iloc[x-1,y] > 0):
        z=np.log(data.iloc[x,y])-np.log(data.iloc[x-1,y]) 
        
    elif np.logical_and(data.iloc[x,y] > 0, data.iloc[x-1,y] == 0):
        z= 1
        
    elif np.logical_and(data.iloc[x,y] == 0, data.iloc[x-1,y] > 0):
        z= -1
        
    elif np.logical_and(data.iloc[x,y] == 0, data.iloc[x-1,y] == 0):
        z= 0
        
    else:
        print("error")
        
    log_diff.append(z)
    x=x+1

print(log_diff)
```

This piece of code seems to be working right for me, however, I do not know how to change the y value yet. I tried to nest this loop into another loop that should change the y-value once the last row has been reached, but I only got wrong results with that (already tried to nest this loop into another while-loop and into another if-loop). It would be great if anyone could tell me how I can change the column after the code has reached the last row of a respective column.

Answer (score 1):

you can use iterrows iteritems

```
for row_index, row in data.iterrows():
    for col_name, cell_value in row.iteritems():
        result.at[row_index, col_name] = cell_value + 1
```